# How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

I need extract the 24 numbers generated in this array and post to php for: $number1=; ... $number24=;
What's the best practice?

```
var usedNums = new Array(76);

function newCard() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    setSquare(i);
  }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare) {
  var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
  var newNum;
  var colPlace = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
  do {
    newNum = (colPlace[thisSquare] * 15) + getNewNum() + 1;
  }
  while (usedNums[newNum]);
  usedNums[newNum] = true;
  document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 75);
}

function anotherCard() {
  for (var i = 1; i < usedNums.length; i++) {
    usedNums[i] = false;
  }
  newCard();
}
```

Source : https://codepen.io/koriwade/pen/BoOqGM

Many Thanks

Comment: you cant pass javascript variable to php directly, set value in html and you can get it int the php.

Comment: You should use a fetch request to pass data from client side to server side. PHP renders before javascript, so it is impossible to get the computed javascript variables at PHP runtime.

Comment: every number that's generated is in `usedNums`, if you want to pass those number to PHP, just send an xmlhttprequest

Comment: There are two main features for passing data from a page to PHP: form element and AJAX.

Comment: Having “numbered variable names” like $number1, …, $number24, is definitively not a “best practice”, not even a good one - **use arrays** for stuff like this.

Comment: FYI: _“What's the best practice?”_ - downvote from me for that. Same as the frequent “what is the best way to do x” questions, to me this translates to “I have not bothered to do my own research on this at all.” We could discuss what the pros & cons are of several different approaches _you_ come up with maybe, but just going “what’s best practice” shows way too little effort IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JSON object like `{"num1":"value1","num2":"value2"}`

The pass it to PHP via ajax request.

On PHP side you will receive an array once you `json_decode`

and then use [`extract`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp) function to map the array key as variables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass the js variables to php because the php runs on server side. But there are several ways of passing variables from JavaScript to PHP.

1. Send the information in a form as stated here
2. Pass it in Ajax
3. Make an HTTP request via an XMLHttpRequest request
4. Save the data in a cookie

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same thing. It's like "Driving" and "Operating a car"

Answer (score 0):

**With the help of ajax you can pass js variable to the PHP.**